# Excel VBA - Check if dates fall within a dynamic range if they have a matching name and title, then take corrective action

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am trying to create a turnover report by graphing how many years someone stays in each position (Job Title). I have figured out how to remove exact duplicates and duplicate Start/End dates, however I'm stuck on the final cleanup step. Cleaning up date range for dates that overlap each other, and removing rows for the overlapping dates. This way I am not counting the same day multiple times.

Here is a simplified set of the data I am working with: 
[image]

I need to define a range by matching names:

John K. = Rows 2-6

Then to only check dates with a matching Job Title:

Sales = Rows 2, 5, 6

Sr. Sales = Rows 3

Sales Mng. = Rows 4

Then for arrays with more than 1 row, check if Start Dates and End Dates fall within each other and ether: 1. Create new row with earliest start date that over laps, latest start date that over laps, and deletes original rows that overlap. 2. Use a loop with Yes/No questions to update an existing row with widest range of overlapping dates and delete rows that fall within that range.

For example, with John K. I would need it to remove rows 5 and 6 as they fall within the date range for row 2, but rows 3 and 4 do not need to be deleted as they are a different Job Title.

For Dom Q., There would be no changes needed as none of his dates fall within each other.

For Henry S., I would need to update D10 to be D11, then delete row 11.

The dataset I will be running this on is 200,000 rows so unfortunately it is too large to manually correct. I saw some good formulas for checking if date ranges fall within each other, however I am not sure how to make them dynamic enough to check only matching names and titles.

Thank you in advance for your thoughts on this and I am happy to provide more data/context if needed.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service. Yet, we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics on [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to [re-take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Afterwards, please update your question with the VBA code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve. We will be here waiting for you. Ready to assist and help you finalize *your code*.

Comment: One issue with your algorhytm, how do you wish to deal with duplicities (what if there are two John K.'s ?)

Comment: This is just a sample set of data I made to imulate what the data I am working with is like. Each person actually has a unique ID that I will be using as a control instead of thier name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around that takes additional manual steps but is still faster than correcting the data line by line. It also requires me to separate the data before hand by Job Title and is entirely dependent on being sorted in a specific way to work correctly.

First make the following sorts:

-Sort Job End Date by A to Z

-Sort Job Start Date by A to Z

-Sort Provider by A to Z

Then I add 3 new columns at the end of my dataset:

New Column 1: End Date Check - To give a checkable end date to blank Job end Date cells

```
=IF(R2="",TODAY(),R2)
```

New Column 2: Q <= above AE - Must start in row 3. If Provider (Name) is the same in the row above, check if Job Start Date is less than or equal to the Job End Date in the row above.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B3=OFFSET(B3,-1,0))*(Q3<=OFFSET(AE3,-1,0)))
```

New Column 3: IF AF = 1, AE >= above AE - Must start in row 3. If New Column 2 equals 1, check if End Date is greater than or equal to the end date above it.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((AF3=1)*(AE3>=OFFSET(AE3,-1,0)))
```

The end result with unnecessary columns hidden looks like this:
[Excel Data Sample 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kHsE.png)

After prepping the data I run the following macro. This will start at Cell AF3, check if the value of the cell is 1, if not, it will increase the value of the Current Row (C_Row) and the Previous Row (P_Row) by 1 and check again until it reaches a blank cell. If an AF cell is 1, it will check if the corresponding AG cell is 1 as well. If AG is 1, it will copy the value of the current rows Job End Date and paste it as value only into the previous row's Job End Date and delete the current row, thus creating the largest overlapping time period in a single row and removing the conflicting row. If AE does not equal 1, it will just delete the current row as the overlapping dates fall entirely within the row above it.

```
Sub Aging_Overlapping_Dates()

Dim C_Row As Long: C_Row = 3
Dim P_Row As Long: P_Row = 2

    'Loops until AF = Blank
    Do While Not Cells(C_Row, "AF") = ""
        'Checks if AF is 1
        If Cells(C_Row, "AF") = 1 Then
            'If AF is 1, check if AG is 1
            If Cells(C_Row, "AG") = 1 Then
                'Moves Job End Date to the previous row and deletes current row
                Cells(C_Row, "R").Copy
                Cells(P_Row, "R").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                Rows(C_Row).Select
            End If
            'Deletes Current Row if AF or AG is 1
            Rows(C_Row).Select
            Selection.EntireRow.Delete
        Else
        'Increase row count if row was not deleted
        C_Row = C_Row + 1
        P_Row = P_Row + 1
        End If
    Loop

End Sub
```